# iterating with django customized filters

Tags: python, django, django-filter

[image]

SO i'm trying to use symbols on my textarea to edit the users input when it's been displayed on the website, but my problem is after getting all the text within the symbols i.e ( __ myText __ ), The output isn't what it's meant to be,
[image]

this is the output

[image]

and this is the input.

Python isn't iterating through the article completely as the code above tells it to but instead it just stops at the first text in-between the double-underscore(_).

Comment: Please paste the code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in very easy way using replace string function like below :-

For example :-

```
value = "anhskdjfhkj kjsdhf kjdhsfk kjdhfm kjdsf mjgfsnmbgdsf ksdgfnm __python is very__ jain kjfdhkf kjgdffsdbhgfds mjhgfd __django__ sjkdfhsdkjfh kjgdfs"
find_val = re.findall("__(.*?)__", value.lstrip('\n'))
for i in find_val:
    b = f'<mark><i style="color:black;">{i}</mark>'
    value = value.replace("__{}__".format(i), b)
print (value)
```

Below is the output :-

```
anhskdjfhkj kjsdhf kjdhsfk kjdhfm kjdsf mjgfsnmbgdsf ksdgfnm <mark><i style="color:black;">python is very</mark> jain kjfdhkf kjgdffsdbhgfds mjhgfd <mark><i style="color:black;">django</mark> sjkdfhsdkjfh kjgdfs
```

Comment: I'm grateful, thank you

Comment: If the answer solves you problem, please accept it.

Comment: Yeah, it did solve it. Thanks a lot